# Why isn't my AlarmManager setRepeating repeating?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I've created an AlarmManager that should run repeatedly and start a service. My problem is it only runs once. I can't figure out what is wrong. For now I've attached creation of the AlarmManager to a button.

This is part of the MenuActivity class:

```
private void startUpdateService() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Registering AlarmManager");

    Intent service = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, UpdateService.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(MenuActivity.this, 0, service, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000, 10*1000, pendingIntent);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch(view.getId()) {
    case R.id.button_calendar:
        Intent calendarIntent = new Intent(this, CalendarActivity.class);
        if(Util.isOnline(this)){
            startActivity(calendarIntent);
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(MenuActivity.this, R.string.toast_is_online, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        break;
    case R.id.button_settings:
        startUpdateService();           
        Toast.makeText(MenuActivity.this, "Startet alarm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();           
        break;
    }

}
```

Initial alarm is working fine, but it won't repeat.
Anyone that knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I didn't realise the service needed to be stopped in order to be started again either. Thank you for posting your findings. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen few problems with running service straight from the alarm. I had it too. What i did, was replacing the service by the broadcast reciver which fires up the service.  Why won't you try it too? It's explained well in [Advanced Android](http://commonsware.com/AdvAndroid/), ver 1 is available on CC licence.

Comment: Thank you. I created a receiver, but experienced the same problem there. The problem was that the service itself wouldn't run more than once. The receiver was called as it should every 10th second. However, I added stopSelf() to the service and now the service is ran every time.
Conclusion: AlarmManager was working, but service wasn't ran. I don't know if my solution is best practice, but it works.

Comment: Are you sure you use the service correctly? Maybe you want to start service every 10 seconds but android keeps it alive? That would explain the need of using stopSelf(). I preasume you are using onCreate() or onStart() to handle the service job. Consider using onHandleIntent() instead. When you solve this problem you can skip the receiver and come back to alarm-firing-service solution. It's obvious that the service is the problem here, not the alarm nor it's repeatability.

Comment: Did as ou suggested. Now it works just fine, no need to stop the service.
Thank you.